# Ajax request seems to fail in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

The following jQuery code returns an xml file from the Met Office datapoint and should alert the user with an attribute in the xml data:-

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/324246?res=daily&key=myapikey",
            dataType: "xml",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (text) {
                myValue = $(text).find("Period Rep").first().attr("W");
                alert(myValue);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Not working");
            }
        })
```

This works fine in Chrome and does what I expect, but in IE8 the error function is called.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or why IE doesn't want to work?

*(Note: I know IE8 is far from ideal but I have to support it for this application unfortunately.  There's no way around this at present)*

Comment: You try make request to another domain?

Comment: I was wondering that but how would that explain Chrome working?

Comment: What version of jQuery? as of version 2.x it only supports IE9+

Comment: My application is using 1.10.2

Comment: Try passing the parameters as object data. Also, (this is for jquery versions prior to 1.9 but try it anyway) change the property `method` to `type`. Did you try with the XMLHttpRequest object directly?

Comment: set `cache: false, ` and try once

Comment: @dreamweiver - this didn't work.

Comment: Can you try printing the error object , `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert('Error 6: jqXHR = ' + jqXHR + '\ntextStatus = ' + textStatus + '\nerrorThrown = ' + errorThrown); blnError = true; }`

Comment: Also you can try passing empty data object , `data:"{}",`

Comment: Error 6: jqxhr=[object Object]
textStatus = error
errorThrown = error

Comment: Empty data object did nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Before request and

```
crossDomain: true
```

as ajax option

Comment: Nope...doesn't work.  I get a message telling  me that the page is trying to access information that might pose a security risk, but once I've dismissed it the error function runs again.  Chrome still works fine.